# Check latest value in table and add to it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Since I got several "projects" that should contain many questions each, I have a question-page where I fill a videolink, four answers and four drow-down lists where the user is able to set points for every answer.

However, in the database I have two tables.

One table, "question", with the columns: pid(project-id), qid(question-id) and question_link. The other table, "answer_det", has the following columns: pid, qid, aid, answer and points.

When I fill and execute my question page I have made so every answer gets an id. In the table "answer_det", Pid, Aid, answer and points is being set. This is how it looks like:
[image]

The "question" table when I insert the first question for the first project with Pid=1 :

[image]

What I want to do now is to also set the qid(question-id). I'm not sure how to do it, but I think that I should have a code that checks the maximum qid of the pid and add 1 to it so every new question for the same project get a new qid. If the pid isn't in the table, then the qid should get the value "1".

So if you look at the first picture, the qid should be 1 on every showed row since all the four answers belongs to the same question, which is the first one for the project with pid=1. So if I would like to add a question to the same project, it should look the same but with the qid=2 and so on. If I then add a new(first) question for the project 2, the qid should begin on 1 and so on. Then, if i would like to add a new question again for the first project, the code should check that the maximum qid is 2 where pid is 1, and then insert a new question with answers but with qid=3.

It should work at almost the same way on the table "question", which you see on the second picture. When the first question is created, except from what I described should happen on the "answer_det"-table, I want the first question for the first project(the one with pid=1) to also have qid=1 and the link that I filled. The second question for the project with pid=1 should then get qid=2. If i add a first question for a new project, it should then be pid=2 and qid=1. Then, if I want to att a third question to the first question it should see that pid=1 has 2 questions(qid=2) and add 1 to is so the third questions looks like pid=1 and qid=3.

This is the code that I have now, and nothing of it inserts anything in the qid in neither of the two tables.

```html
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo mysqli_connect_error();
}

$pid5 = $_POST['pid4'];

$video = $_POST['videolink1'];
    
$aid1 = $_POST['a1'];
$aid2 = $_POST['a2'];
$aid3 = $_POST['a3'];
$aid4 = $_POST['a4'];    
    
$answ1 = $_POST['ans1'];
$answ2 = $_POST['ans2'];
$answ3 = $_POST['ans3'];
$answ4 = $_POST['ans4'];
    
$point1 = $_POST['pointset1'];  
$point2 = $_POST['pointset2'];  
$point3 = $_POST['pointset3'];  
$point4 = $_POST['pointset4'];

$que = "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid1','$answ1','$point1');";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid2','$answ2','$point2');";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid3','$answ3','$point3');";
$que .= "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','','$aid4','$answ4','$point4');";
    
$que .= "INSERT INTO question VALUES('$pid5','','$video');";

$run = mysqli_multi_query($mysqli,$que);
if($run)
{
 echo "<br>Information stored successfully";

}
else
{
 echo mysql_error();
}


?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `AUTO_INCREMENT` suit your needs?

Comment: @Jan No it wouldn't. The table could look like: pid=1 qid=1, pid=1 qid=2, pid=1 qid=3, pid=2 qid=1,pid=2 qid=2. Therefore, it wouln't work.

Comment: This appears to be a close duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34514472/check-latest-id-and-add-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an answer and a suggestion for you :]

### Answer:

If you want to add the qid to each question_det you need to insert the **question** before inserting the **question_det** and obtain the qid with mysqli_last_insert() function:

```
$que = "INSERT INTO question VALUES('$pid5','','$video');";

mysqli_query($mysqli,$que);

$qid = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // get last inserted ID of the question

$que = "INSERT INTO answer_det VALUES('$pid5','$qid','$aid1','$answ1','$point1');";
// and so on
```

### My suggestion:

I think you may need to structure your database differently.

This is your structure

```
// question table
| pid | qid |    question_link   |
|-----|-----|--------------------|
|  1  |  0  | http://example.com |

// question_det
| pid | qid | aid | answer | points |
|-----|-----|-----|--------|--------|
|  1  |     |  1  | Yes    | 10     |
```

It's bad practice to use a totally different column as PRIMARY KEY... for example your table question the PRIMARY_KEY should be **qid** not **pid**; for the question_det table same problem the PRIMARY_KEY should be **aid** not **pid** and both should be set to AUTO_INCREMENT so every time you insert a new question or question_det it automatically increase the qid and aid columns

You should have something like this instead:

```
//create a table called 'project' to store them:
| pid |   project_name   |
|-----|------------------|
|  1  | project 1        |
|  2  | amazing project! |

//create a table called 'question':

| qid | pid |      question    |   question_link   |
|-----|-----|------------------|-------------------|
|  1  |  1  | super question   | http:/example.com |
|  2  |  1  | question?        | http:/example.com |
|  3  |  2  | more questions?  | http:/example.com |

// and finally create a table called 'answer'

| aid | qid |     answer    | points |
|-----|-----|---------------|--------|
|  1  |  1  | Yes           | 10     |
|  2  |  1  | No            | 20     |
|  3  |  1  | Maybe         | 30     |
|  4  |  1  | I do not know | 40     |
```

NOTE: Each table ID should be set to AUTO_INCREMENT

This is how the PHP code should look like:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$pid = $_POST['pid']; // project ID
$question = $_POST['question']; // question may have a 'title' ?
$video = $_POST['videolink1'];

// the asnwers!
$answ1 = $_POST['ans1'];
$answ2 = $_POST['ans2'];
$answ3 = $_POST['ans3'];
$answ4 = $_POST['ans4'];

// the points!
$point1 = $_POST['pointset1'];
$point2 = $_POST['pointset2'];
$point3 = $_POST['pointset3'];
$point4 = $_POST['pointset4'];

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$query = "INSERT INTO question (pid,question,question_link) VALUES ({$pid},'{$question}','{$video}');";


if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)) {
    echo "<br>Question Information stored successfully!";

    $qid = mysqli_insert_id($conn); // get last inserted ID of the question

    $query = "INSERT INTO answer(qid, answer, points) VALUES ({$qid},'{$answ1}',{$point1});";
    $query .= "INSERT INTO answer(qid, answer, points) VALUES ({$qid},'{$answ2}',{$point2});";
    $query .= "INSERT INTO answer(qid, answer, points) VALUES ({$qid},'{$answ3}',{$point3});";
    $query .= "INSERT INTO answer(qid, answer, points) VALUES ({$qid},'{$answ4}',{$point4});";

    if(mysqli_multi_query($conn,$query)) {
        echo "<br>Questions stored successfully!";
    } else {
        echo mysqli_errno($conn);
    }
} else {
    echo mysqli_errno($conn);
}
```

The database SQL structure should be something like this as well:

```
CREATE TABLE `project` (
`pid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`project_name` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`pid`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `question` (
 `qid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `pid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `question` VARCHAR(60) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `question_link` VARCHAR(300) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`qid`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `answer` (
 `aid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `qid` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `answer` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `points` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`aid`))
ENGINE = MyISAM
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```