# Check latest id and add 1

Tags: mysql, database-design

Since I got several "projects" that should contain many questions each, I have a question-page where I fill a videolink, four answers and four drow-down lists where the user is able to set points for every answer.

However, in the database I have two tables. 
When I fill and execute my question page I have made so every answer gets an id. In the table "answer_det", Pid, Aid, answer and points is being set. This is how it looks like:

[image]

The "question" table when I insert the first question for the first project(Pid=1) :

[image]

What I want to do now is to also set the qid(question-id). I'm not sure how to do it, but I think that I should have a code that checks the maximum qid of the pid and add 1 to it so every new question for the same project get a new qid. If the pid isn't in the table, then the qid should get the value "1".

So if you look at the first picture, the qid should be 1 on every showed row since all the four answers belongs to the same question, which is the first one for the project with pid=1. So if I would like to add a question to the same project, it should look the same but with the qid=2 and so on. If I then add a new(first) question for the project 2, the qid should begin on 1 and so on. Then, if i would like to add a new question again for the first project, the code should check that the maximum qid is 2 where pid is 1, and then insert a new question with answers but with qid=3.

It should work the same way on the table "question", which you see on the second picture. When the first question is created, I want the first question for the first project(the one with pid=1) to also have qid=1 and the link that I filled. The second question for the project with pid=1 should then get qid=2. If i add a first question for a new project, it should then be pid=2 and qid=1. 
This is the code that I have now, and nothing of it inserts anything in the qid in neither of the two tables.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

SO is **not a free coding service**

Comment: It would be helpful for you if you could post some code.

Comment: If you didnt start to code..Start over your database design and try to use "data-relations" such as many-to-many etc..If you started share your code..

Comment: The most robust and easiest way to achieve this is to let mysql create the ids. This can be done by defining a coumn als "auto increment".

Comment: Not only do I agree with everything @maxhb says, but there's even more to it.  Without an auto increment primary key, the algorithm you suggest has a race condition.  If 2 questions are added at the same time, the prices would set both IDs to the same thing.  And as others have said, the relationships between your tables should be expressed with foreign keys

Comment: @DanFarrell i solved everything with sessions. What I did was to retrieve qid from a previous page and put into qid with the session in my codes:)

Comment: This appears to be a close duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513809/check-latest-value-in-table-and-add-to-it

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a predefined set of projects:

Project 1> Science

Project 2> Maths

Project 3> History.....and so on.

I suggest you create a separate table for projects that would have projectID and projectName columns.

Now in your question-page, have these projects in a dropdown(select option) format with projectID as the option value and projectName as the dropdown select name.

Now you have a select option for project name, an input field for question_link and other select options for answers and their weight-age. Now when you insert this form (this question) try coding the following logic (I will just try to write in pseudo-code manner)

```html
//first check if this project already has questions in the question table.
 So do something like

SELECT* FROM question WHERE pid = $post['projectID'] ORDER BY qid DESC 
// or you could do SELECT TOP 1

// CASE1: if this project never had any questions, the select would return null. 
//Hence this is a first question for this project. Then simply write an insert query that 
//would insert $post['projectID'] to pid and 1 in qid (since this is the first question). 
//Also, insert a series of rows in the answer_det table that will have $post['projectID'] 
//to pid and 1 for qid and the answer and points as submitted.


// CASE2: if this project already has 1 or more questions, your select query from above 
//will return some rows and if you pick $row[0]['qid'], this would be the highest number 
//value for question (qid) as we selected using  ORDER BY qid DESC. Now, simply do inserts 
//in both the tables like you would do as above but this time, in the qid field in both 
//the tables, instead of inserting 1, you would insert qid => $row[0]['qid'] + 1.
//You wouldn't need to know what the qid was, all you need is to get the last qid and add 
//1 to it.

//Also, you can create a separate page to add the projectName as you feel to add new
//projects and insert this into the project_table and this will begin to show up in the
//select options when you are adding new questions.
```